# jquery each if statement addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, each

```js
var count = 0;
window.onload = function(){

    $("#add").click(function () {
        var bugValue = $("#bug").val();
        var author = $("#author").val();
        var description = $("#description").val();
        var date = $("#datepicker").val();
        var open = $("#openParent");
        if(!checkInput(bugValue) || !checkInput(author) || !checkInput(date)) {
            alert("Bitte einen Wert für Bug, Author und Due Date eingeben");
        } else {
            var column = $("<div class='column'></div>");
            var entry = $("<div class='portlet'></div>");
            var blueBug = $("<div class='portlet-header'></div>").text(bugValue);
            var name1 = $("<div class='portlet-content'></div>").text(author);
            var dueDate1 = $("<div class='portlet-content'></div>").text(date);
            var text1 = $("<div class='portlet-content'></div>").text(description);

            $(dueDate1).addClass("datepicker");
            $(entry).append(blueBug);
            $(entry).append(name1);
            $(entry).append(dueDate1);
            $(entry).append(text1);
            $(column).append(entry);
            $(open).after(entry);

            count++;
        }
    });

    $( ".column" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".column",
        handle: ".portlet-header",
        cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
        placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
    });

    $( ".portlet" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
        .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

    $( ".portlet-toggle" ).on( "click", function() {
        var icon = $( this );
        icon.toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick" );
        icon.closest( ".portlet" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });

    $( function() {
        var today = new Date();
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            minDate: today
        });
    } );

    $("#delete").click(function () {
        var closed = $(".closed");
        for(var i=closed.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            closed.remove();
        }
    });

    $("#todayBugs").click(function (){
        var d = new Date();
        var portlet = $(".portlet");
        var twoDigitMonth = ((d.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (d.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (d.getMonth()+1);
        var today = (twoDigitMonth + '/'  + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
        /*for(var i=0; i<=count; i++) {
            if(today == $("#datepicker").val()) {
                $(portlet[i]).addClass("highlight");
            }
        }*/
        $(portlet).each(function () {
            if(today == $("#datepicker").val()) {
                $(this).addClass("highlight");
            }
        })
    });

    $("#column").click(function () {
        $(".column").css("width", "140px");
        var columnText = $("#columnText").val();
        var column = $("<div class='columnDIV'></div>");
        var header = $("<div class='header'></div>").text(columnText);
        var newContent = $("<div class='new-content'></div>");
        var closed = $("#closedDIV");

        if(!checkInput(columnText)) {
            alert("Bitte einen Wert eingeben");
        } else {
            $(column).append(header);
            $(column).append(newContent);
            $(closed).before(column);
        }
    });
};

function checkInput(input) {
    return input!=="";
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.row {
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.column {
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.columnDIV {
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: #454545;
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.portlet {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0em;
}

.portlet-header {
    background-color: #007fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
}
.portlet-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.portlet-content {
    padding: 0.4em;
}
.portlet-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.header  {
    padding: 0.4em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}

#add{
    float: right;
}

#addcolumn{
    float: right;
}

#title{
    float: left;
}

.text{
    width: 218px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.textarea{
    width: 580px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.clearer{
    clear: both;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bug-List</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bugs.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bugs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialogHTML"></div>
<div class="wrapper">

    <h1>Bug-List</h1><br/>

    <form name="bugForm" action="#">
        <div id="title">
            <label>Bug:</label>
            <input class="text" id="bug" type="text" name="bug" size="10" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Author:</label>
            <input class="text" id="author" type="text" name="author" size="10" />
            <div class="clearer"></div><br/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Description:</label>
            <textarea class="textarea" id="description" name ="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br/>
            <div class="clearer"></div><br/>
        </div>

        <form>
            Due Date:
            <input type="text" id="datepicker"><br>
        </form>

        <input id="add" type="button" value="Add" /><br/>

        <hr/>

        <input id="todayBugs" type="button" value="Today´s Due Bugs" />
        <input id="delete" type="button" value="Delete closed" />

        <div id="addcolumn">
        <input id="column" type="button" value="Add Column" />
        <input class="text" id="columnText" type="text" name="new" size="10" />
        </div>

        <hr/>

        <fieldset id="field">
            <legend>Bugs</legend>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="header" id="openParent">Open</div>
                <div class="open-content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="header">In Progress</div>
                <div class="progress"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column" id="closedDIV">
                <div class="header">Closed</div>
                <div class="column closed"></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to select all portlet elements that are due today and add them to the class highlight.
The problem is, that it adds the class to all portlet elements if it finds one that is due today, not only to the due portlet.
It doesn´t work neither with a for loop, nor with the jQuery each().

```
$("#todayBugs").click(function (){
    var d = new Date();
    var portlet = $(".portlet");
    var twoDigitMonth = ((d.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (d.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (d.getMonth()+1);
    var today = (twoDigitMonth + '/'  + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
    /*for(var i=0; i<=count; i++) {
        if(today == $("#datepicker").val()) {
            $(portlet[i]).addClass("highlight");
        }
    }*/
    $(portlet).each(function () {
        if(today == $("#datepicker").val()) {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: can you provide working level [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or snippet

Comment: I just added it, sorry for not adding it before, I am new here

Comment: Any reason why you have a form within a form? You probably meant for that to be a div, but just in case, a form within a form is invalid HTML.

Comment: Oh, you´re right that should be a div. Thank you!